# How to setup multi-signature functions for varies type of transactions

Tags: gnosis-safe

"In case different transactions or assets should require a different number of owners to confirm, we have seen organizations use different Safes with different assets and a different setup of owners and threshold"
so is it possible to setup a Gnosis Safe account which the multi-signature functions can apply to varies type of transactions
i.e
For transferring money in and out from the account -> it takes 5 signatures
For execution of buying NFTs from Opensea -> it takes only 2 signatures [image]

Comment: the article you mention says that organizations simply use different Safes: "we have seen organizations use different Safes with different assets and a different setup of owners and threshold"